# How to rotate PDF 90 degrees using R?

Tags: r

I have already tried the following

```
library(staplr)
rotate_pdf(page_rotation = 90, input_filepath = "test.pdf", output_filepath = "test.pdf", overwrite = TRUE)
```

but no file is being created